# How to identify NICs that are connected to the same machine

Tags: linux, networking

If we have multiple lan cards installed in our server in which any one is connected with lan.can we identify that by command

Answer (score 1):

This is highly dependent on your OS, what are you using?

If you're using Linux, [ethtool](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ethtool) will do this:

```
ethtool --identify <devname>
```

Where devname is like eth1, p1p2, or whatever interface you're actually using.

Answer (score 1):

Ethtool offers a way to do this.

ethtool -p eth0 120 - this will blink the led on eth0 for 120 seconds

Use ethtool option -p, which will make the corresponding LED of physical port to blink.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest is to unplug and replug cables and watch the syslog while you do this. Alternatively you could use ip adddr sh or ifconfig and link the mac address with the physical card.